# printing unicode fails in Python 3.8

Tags: eclipse, unicode, output, python-3.8

I'm running python 3.8.5. My understanding is that Python as of version 3.6 can print unicode with the print() statement. I am calling print() with the following string (as represented by the Eclipse debugger):

The exact code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def getArticles(self, filename):
    print("Parsing XML tree...")
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    print("Done")
    articles = tree.getroot()
    for article in articles:
        for body in article.iter('body'):
            for title in article.iter('article-title'):
                print (title.text) #This is the line that causes the crash
```

> "Certain styrene oligomers have proliferative activity on MCF-7 human\nbreast tumor cells and binding affinity for human estrogen receptor\nα."

and getting the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b1' in position 139: character maps to

I believe it is the α character that's causing the crash. The exact text of the XML tag this string is extracted from is:

```
Certain styrene oligomers have proliferative activity on MCF-7 human


breast tumor cells and binding affinity for human estrogen receptor


&#x003b1;.
```

I hate to ask a question so closely related to others that have been asked before, but I couldn't find anything dealing with this exact issue. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Still haven't solved the problem, but I did determine that `&#x003b1` is a hexadecimal HTML5 representation of α. So I think the issue isn't actually printing unicode, but representing HTML5 hexadecimal codes.

Also, the python IDLE can handle a statement like:

```
print("α")
```

while Eclipse, which I'm running the above code on, cannot. It won't even save the .py file if it contains the α character. I confirmed from within-script that I'm running Python 3.8.5 within Eclipse. So I feel like the problem is probably with the IDE?

SOLVED:
The problem was with Eclipse. I added the following line to the end of eclipse.ini and it now works properly:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: No, your assumption is wrong: In general, Python cannot print all Unicode characters with `print`. Print is linked to console, and so Python should downgrade characters to a safe set provided by the console (or just ASCII as fall back). Now this problem is found just in Windows (other OSes have converted to UTF-8 as standard charset, but ev. on with `C` locales as administrative user). OTOH you should not print on console on windows. OTOH print is handy for debugging/testing.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
The problem was with Eclipse. I added the following line to the end of eclipse.ini and it now works properly:

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8